# AngularJS $timeout returning bad request

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angular-controller

I am trying to use the $timeout and use the following code within my controller:

```
     $scope.counter = 0;
        var updateCounter = function() {
            $scope.counter++;
            $timeout(updateCounter, 1000);
        };
            updateCounter();
```

However, when calling updateCounter(), I get the following error: [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/badreq?p0=function%20()][1]

Thank you very much for any help and input.
Steffen

Comment: Please check, you passed string type url to $http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
  })
  .controller('testController', ['$scope', '$timeout',
    function($scope, $timeout) {

      $scope.counter = 0;
      var updateCounter = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        $timeout(updateCounter, 1000);
      };
      updateCounter();
    }
  ])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">

</body>

</html>
```

Your code is working fine for me. you might be forgot to inject $timeout in your controller.